# Chrome : Native messaging Error: Access to the specified native messaging host is forbidden

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

I am running the Native messaging sample app.
(http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/api/nativeMessaging/).

I have  added registry key

```
 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Google\Chrome\NativeMessagingHosts\com.google.chrome.example.echo
```

When i am connecting to native host i am getting error:

```
Failed to connect: Access to the specified native messaging host is forbidden.
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to **[the docs](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html#native-messaging-host)** you need to explicitely give your extension access to the NativeMessagingHost in the latter's manifest:

```
"allowed_origins": [
    "chrome-extension://<your_extension's_ID>/"
]
```

Comment: ExpertSystem thanks for reply. I have corrected id now it is showing another error "Error when communicating with the native messaging host"

Comment: This is a totally different problem. So, I suggest posting a new answer and describing exactly what you have done. "Error when communicating..." is a very generic error message and has a wide range of possible causes, so you'll probably need to post some code.